# How to change permissions of word document programatically using office.js apis?

Tags: office-js

I'm creating a sample office word add-in and for that I went through the api documentation of office.js but i could not find How to change the permissions of Word document through program.
We can change the permissions of document from the manifest.xml using a  tag and get it in program using the mode property of document object. But in my case i need to change permissions from program.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions you specify in the manifest are the permissions your *add-in* requires, they are not affecting any permissions on the document itself.

It isn't possible to manipulate the document's permissions from Office.js. I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, @Marc it isn't possible right now from the office js, that I understood from the documentation.
But, Is there any way in Office js from which we can make document readOnly or read-write.
I want to do something like a check in check out functionality which will be same as google online docs. Suppose, there are two users #user1 and #user2 and if #user1 opened the doc first then #user2 can only read the document.

Comment: This is functionality on the backend. If your document in on OneDrive or SharePoint it will handle collaboration scenarios automatically. This isn't something you can/should control from an add-in.